# Error in accessing HTTPS link, shows 403 forbidden and UnknownHostException

Tags: java, http-status-code-403, internet-radio

I am making an app to listen online radio. So i sent a HTTPS radio site to it.`hplayRadioStream("https://radio.itechnepal.com/pathibhara/stream");`

So i tried to access the input stream using the following code:

```
 private static void hplayRadioStream(String spec) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JavaLayerException {
     try{
 URL url= new URL(spec);
    HttpsURLConnection huc= (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      InputStream response= huc.getInputStream();
      Player player= new Player(response);
      player.play();
     }
       catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);
     }
    }
```

And it gives 403 forbidden error. So i tried implementing this using SSLSocketFactory using following code:

```
   private static void hplayRadioStream(String spec) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JavaLayerException {
     try{
        Security.addProvider ( new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
     System.setProperty ("java.protocol.handler.pkgs",
                  "com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol");

SSLSocketFactory factory =
              (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
          SSLSocket socket =
              (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(spec, 443);      
       socket.startHandshake();
  InputStream response= socket.getInputStream();
      Player player= new Player(response);
      player.play();
     }
       catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);
     }
    }
```

And this gives UnknownHostException. So when i tried to access its IP address, using "nslookup" ,"tracert" and "ping" , they couldn't find the domain or show non-existent domain. But if it is non-existent then why the original site is playing the same stream from here: http://www.pathibharafm.org/. Even the browser shows 403 forbidden message while pasting the stream link in next tab. Please do help.